# Hibernate: Implement a SELECT with GROUP BY and aggregate functions

Tags: java, hibernate, aggregate

I want to:

```
SELECT date(some_date), SUM(value1 * value2)
FROM some_table
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY date(some_date)
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

But I have no idea how to convert it to Hibernate syntax, especially the `date(some_date)` part and `SUM(value1 * value2)` parts

Answer (score 0):

Lets imagine that you have mapped you take some_table to a class named  SomeTable.  Your HQL query will look like this:

```
select to_char(t.someDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), sum(t.value1*t.value2)
from SomeTable t 
group by to_char(t.someDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
order by t.id desc;
```

What is important to be noted here is that you need to cast the date to a char in order to group by it.